# Scala Multiple Nested Case Clases

Tags: scala, case-class

Good day everyone, I create the following case class on SCALA:

```
sealed abstract class Value;
  case class U(name: String) extends Value
  case class L(name: String) extends Value
  case class B(name: String) extends Value

  sealed abstract class Term
  case class Var(name: String) extends Term //variable name
  case class Val(value: Value) extends Term //value

sealed abstract class Pattern //patterns
  case class BGP(subject: Term, predicate: Term, obj: Term) extends Pattern
  case class And( pat1: Pattern, pat2: Pattern) extends Pattern
  case class Filter(pred: Predicate, pattern: Pattern ) extends Pattern


def function(p: Pattern): Unit = p match { 
    case BGP(Var(x), Val(y), Val(z)) => {
      val con:conv = new conv()
      val valor:Value = Val(y).value
}
```

Then, as you can see, BGP contains Term and extends to pattern, Val contains Values and extends to Term, and U,L,B contains Strings and extends to Value, 
In my function I want to access to the strings that contains the U or L or B case classes,  the variable valor = Val(y).value contains a U class for example, but when I write valor.XXXX don't appear me the name option. The big question is How can I do to accesss to the String name from U?

Comment: You treat your `U`, `L`, `B` class instance as a `Value`, *which doesn't have any methods/fields declared* but you expect it to magically have them when you want? :D

Comment: Yes, I expect the magic properties from SCALA, XD, @flavian gave me the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just define it on `Value` which btw could be a `trait`.

```
sealed trait Value {
  def name: String
}
case class U(name: String) extends Value
case class L(name: String) extends Value
case class B(name: String) extends Value
```

Comment: This classes in this moment are under a trait: trait SPARQLInterpreter {


  sealed abstract class Value;
  case class URI(name: Node) extends Value
  case class Literal(name: Node) extends Value
  case class BlankNode(name: Node) extends Value

Comment: @VladimirRincon I don't see how that makes a difference, can you not access the `Value` class, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Ok @flavian, I see your point and I implemented, you are right and it works, thank you!!